# Constants not loaded by compiler

Tags: c, posix, time.h

I started studying POSIX timers, so I started also doing some exercises, but I immediately had some problems with the compiler.
When compiling this code, I get some strange messages about macros like CLOCK_MONOTONIC. Those are defined in various libraries like time.h etc. but the compiler gives me errors as if they are not defined.

It is strange because I am using a Fedora 16, and some of my friends with Ubuntu get less compiler errors than I :-O

I am compiling with `gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -lrt`

Here the errors I get:

- `struct sigevent sigeventStruct` **gives**:

  ```
  storage size of ‘sigeventStruct’ isn’t known
  unused variable ‘sigeventStruct’ [-Wunused-variable]
  Type 'sigevent' could not be resolved
  unknown type name ‘sigevent’
  ```
- `sigeventStruct.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL` **gives**:

  ```
  ‘SIGEV_SIGNAL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  request for member ‘sigev_notify’ in something not a structure or union
  Field 'sigev_notify' could not be resolved
  ```
- `if(timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, sigeventStruct, numero1) == -1)` **gives**:

  ```
  implicit declaration of function ‘timer_create’ [-Wimplicit-function- declaration]
  ‘CLOCK_MONOTONIC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  Symbol 'CLOCK_MONOTONIC' could not be resolved
  ```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{
        timer_t numero1;
        struct sigevent sigeventStruct;
        sigeventStruct.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
        if(timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, sigeventStruct, numero1) == -1)
        {
                printf( "Errore: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, instead of having the errors in point-form, just copy them exactly as they are inside a `<pre></pre>` block in the question.

Comment: Ok next time I will keep in consideration your suggestion

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, you can compile your code with `-std=gnu99` instead of `-std=c99` if you want to have the identifiers `SIGEV_SIGNAL`,  `sigeventStruct`, and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` available.

As noted by @adwoodland these identifiers are declared when `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is set to a value >= `199309L`, which is the case with `-std=gnu99`. You can also use `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L -std=c99` or have the macro defined in source code.

Secondly, see the `timer_create` prototype,  you have to pass pointers as the second and the third argument to the function:

```
timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &sigeventStruct, &numero1)
                              ^                ^
```

Also you have to include the standard header `string.h` for `strerror` function declaration.

Comment: Good catch on the `timer_t` being a pointer too. I missed that because `-Wall -Wextra` didn't even warn about it!

Comment: I am a bit confused
if I compile with -std=gnu99 still I need #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L to be written in code listing?
When using -std=c99 is the same thing using -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L -std=c99 or -std=c99 and the #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L ?

Comment: @Caterpillar if you use `-std=gnu99` you have nothing to do, `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` will be automatically defined and the value will be > `199309L`. With `-std=c99`, using `-D` or the `#define` solution is equivalent. When using the `#define` just be sure to put the `#define` in a line before the includes of `time.h` and `signal.h`

Comment: I solved a lot of problems but I am still having
CLOCK_MONOTONIC could not be resolved.
I am using -std=gnu99

Answer (score 8):

If you are using `-std=c99` you need to tell gcc you're still using recent versions of POSIX:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
```

*before* any `#include`, or even with `-D` on the command line.

Other errors:

- Missing `#include <string.h>`
- You need a pointer for `timer_create`, i.e. `&sigeventStruct` instead of just `sigeventStruct`

Answer (score 4):

The other answers suggest `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` as the enabling macro.  That certainly works, but it doesn't necessarily enable everything that is in the Single Unix Specification (SUS).   For that, you should set [`_XOPEN_SOURCE`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02), which also automatically sets `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`.  I have a header I call `"posixver.h"` which contains:

```
/*
** Include this file before including system headers.  By default, with
** C99 support from the compiler, it requests POSIX 2001 support.  With
** C89 support only, it requests POSIX 1997 support.  Override the
** default behaviour by setting either _XOPEN_SOURCE or _POSIX_C_SOURCE.
*/

/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 700 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L */
/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 600 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L */
/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 500 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199506L */

#if !defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) && !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE)
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600   /* SUS v3, POSIX 1003.1 2004 (POSIX 2001 + Corrigenda) */
#else
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500   /* SUS v2, POSIX 1003.1 1997 */
#endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ */
#endif /* !_XOPEN_SOURCE && !_POSIX_C_SOURCE */
```

It is tuned for the systems I work with which don't all recognize the 700 value.  If you are working on a relatively modern Linux, I believe you can use 700.  It's in a header so that I only have to change one file when I want to alter the rules.

Comment: Thank you, I keep this library for further purposes

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the CLOCK_MONOTONIC not being defined problem:

As Caterpillar pointed out this is an eclipse bug, more precisely a CDT-Indexer bug with a workaround at [eclipse bugs, comment 12](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=332530#c12)

Comment: You should add what the workaround is in case the link dies

Answer (score 1):

I solved a lot of problems with -std=gnu99 (without specifing any POSIX versions) but I am still having

```
CLOCK_MONOTONIC could not be resolved
```

Searching on internet I found some Eclipse bugreports with people complaining about this. Have to check better if is an Eclipse bug, because with

```
gcc -Wall -w -o Blala timer.c -std=gnu99 -lrt
```

it compiles

Comment: Yes it is a bug of Eclipse's CDT plugin