# Trying to use clock_gettime(), but getting plenty of "undeclared" errors from time.h

Tags: c, time, libraries

I am trying to measure the running time of a function using `clock_gettime()`. I am including `time.h`, I added `-lrt` to the Makefile, and added the right path on Eclipse CDT. However, when I try to compile I keep getting these kinds of errors:

```
experiments.c: In function ‘main’:
experiments.c:137:2: error: unknown type name ‘timespec’
timespec time1, time2;
^
experiments.c:139:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘clock_gettime’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);
^
experiments.c:139:16: error: ‘CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID’ undeclared
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);
```

This happens with any type of `CLOCK_` I try to use. I've been reading plenty of questions/answers and tutorials but haven't been able to find something that helps.

The headers I'm including are:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
```

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 32 bit and compiling on `gcc` with the following `CFLAGS`: `-g -Wall -pedantic -std=c99`

If I add the flag `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L` I get `error: unknown type name ‘timespec’` and warnings about using `timespec`.

This is the part of the code, just in case it helps:

```
timespec time1, time2;
int temp;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);
.
.
.
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);
/*code stuff*/
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time2);
```

Thanks

Comment: What header files are you including?

Comment: There is a note in the man page about `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L`, what are you trying to compile this on?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin compiling on gcc with the following flags: -g -Wall -pedantic -std=c99

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin added the flag `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L` but getting `error: unknown type name ‘timespec’` (edited to add all of this to the question)

Comment: place the '-lrt' at the END of the compile line, because a function is not included from a lib by the linker until AFTER it is referenced in code and the compile/link line is evaluated left to right.

Comment: the calls to clock_gettime() return an error code.  A return of 0 indicates success, a return of -1 indicates a failure.  your code should be checking that return code on every call to clock_gettime().  Also, the prototype for clock_gettime() is defined in the time.h header file, so your code should not include a prototype for the function.

Comment: For me the answer was contained in the question: the code (part of xenomai 3.0.5 install) didn't have `include <time.h>` at the top

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8881675/2943652) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11153394/2943652) answers together I was able to make it work. I had to add the `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` macro, to make sure the preprocessor was getting the library features correctly, which I did by adding this line before all my includes:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
```

Then I started getting a `unknown type name timespec` error, which was happening because you have to tell the compiler explicitly that `timespec` is a `struct`. Fixed it by writing:

```
struct timespec time1, time2;
```

instead of just `timespec time1, time2;`.

Comment: Using 1993 is a bit retrograde. You'd probably succeed with `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` which requests POSIX 2008 support (though you could use `600` for the prior version, 2004, which might be more widely available). You could also use `-std=gnu99` (or `-std=gnu11`) to get them defined without writing a `#define` at the top of your code. As for using `struct timespec`, that is a question of reading the specification for the functions; that's what it says, so that's what you need to use unless you provide `typedef struct timespec timespec;` (but note that you can't do that for `struct stat`).