# Compilation error for using struct itimerspec

Tags: c

I am trying to write a timer in C using timerfd_create() and timer_settime().
I am using CLOCK_MONOTONIC. But though i include these header files,

```
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

struct itimerspec timerValue; //This is how i defined the structure
//some code
g_fdRetryTimer = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0);
```

I am consistently getting the following compilation errors.

```
error: storage size of ‘timerValue’ isn’t known
error: ‘CLOCK_MONOTONIC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Please show your compile command with flags.

Comment: i used gcc ctimer.c -o ctimer.

Answer (score 0):

gcc < 5.1.0 default standard is `-std=gnu90`. Version 5.1.0, changed the default from `-std=gnu90` to `-std=gnu11`.

You should compile your code with `-std=gnu99` to have the identifier `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` available.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881617/constants-not-loaded-by-compiler) might provide more details.